# Different between EventBus vs Handler in android

Tags: android, android-handler, greenrobot-eventbus

I used android `Handler` for step by step processes in my apps. For example, after `setp_1` finished, send message to handler and then start `step_2`.

Now I found `greenrobot EventBus`. I interested in it performance and features. I want to replace android `Handler` with `EventBus` in my app.

So I would like to know what is different between `EventBus` and `Handler`. 
Is `EventBus` alternative to android `Handler`?

Answer (score 0):

event bus is an alternative to listeners
(in version 2 using refection - not sure about 3)